# Need css switch assistance

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a switch using mostly css. The left side of the switch will say Color and the right side will say B&W. All I need is a simple animation that covers the option in use when the switch is clicked. I looked for examples on codepen but everything is with SASS or other different types of code that I don't really know how to edit or implement into my own code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice library which you can use. [Click Here](http://callmenick.com/post/css-toggle-switch-examples)

```css
/* ============================================================
  COMMON
============================================================ */

#wrapper {
  min-width: 600px;
}
.settings {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.settings .row {
  display: table-row;
}
.settings .question,
.settings .switch {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
}
.settings .question {
  width: 600px;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}
/* ============================================================
  COMMON
============================================================ */

.cmn-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -9999px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.cmn-toggle + label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
/* ============================================================
  SWITCH 1 - ROUND
============================================================ */

input.cmn-toggle-round + label {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  -ms-border-radius: 60px;
  -o-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round + label:before,
input.cmn-toggle-round + label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  content: "";
}
input.cmn-toggle-round + label:before {
  right: 1px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  -ms-border-radius: 60px;
  -o-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.4s;
  -o-transition: background 0.4s;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round + label:after {
  width: 58px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -ms-border-radius: 100%;
  -o-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: margin 0.4s;
  -o-transition: margin 0.4s;
  transition: margin 0.4s;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round:checked + label:before {
  background-color: #8ce196;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round:checked + label:after {
  margin-left: 60px;
}
/* ============================================================
  SWITCH 2 - ROUND FLAT
============================================================ */

input.cmn-toggle-round-flat + label {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  -ms-border-radius: 60px;
  -o-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.4s;
  -o-transition: background 0.4s;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round-flat + label:before,
input.cmn-toggle-round-flat + label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
}
input.cmn-toggle-round-flat + label:before {
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  -ms-border-radius: 60px;
  -o-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.4s;
  -o-transition: background 0.4s;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round-flat + label:after {
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  width: 52px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  -webkit-border-radius: 52px;
  -moz-border-radius: 52px;
  -ms-border-radius: 52px;
  -o-border-radius: 52px;
  border-radius: 52px;
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.4s, background 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: margin 0.4s, background 0.4s;
  -o-transition: margin 0.4s, background 0.4s;
  transition: margin 0.4s, background 0.4s;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round-flat:checked + label {
  background-color: #8ce196;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round-flat:checked + label:after {
  margin-left: 60px;
  background-color: #8ce196;
}
/* ============================================================
  SWITCH 3 - YES NO
============================================================ */

input.cmn-toggle-yes-no + label {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
}
input.cmn-toggle-yes-no + label:before,
input.cmn-toggle-yes-no + label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
}
input.cmn-toggle-yes-no + label:before {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  content: attr(data-off);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
input.cmn-toggle-yes-no + label:after {
  background-color: #8ce196;
  content: attr(data-on);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
input.cmn-toggle-yes-no:checked + label:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
input.cmn-toggle-yes-no:checked + label:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(0);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(0);
  -o-transform: rotateY(0);
  transform: rotateY(0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html class="no-js" lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- title and meta -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

  <title>CSS Toggle Switch</title>

  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- js -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

  <div id="wrapper">

    </header>

    <div id="main">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="settings">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="question">
              Color Option?
            </div>
            <div class="switch">
              <input id="cmn-toggle-1" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round" type="checkbox">
              <label for="cmn-toggle-1"></label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /row -->

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- #main -->


  </div>
  <!-- /#wrapper -->


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use javascript? or does it have to be CSS?

If you use javascript, you can alter the state of an elements CSS properties by using document.getElementById('x').style.[ccstag]

i use this to show and hide an option in a menu that are excusive.

```
function Showelement(id,n1){

    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById(n1).style.display = "";

}
```

You could use the same thing, but have your

the element being hidden. The "" will return the CSS for the element back to what it was set in your CSS or style before the JS alteration.

Hope this helps :)